# Weird small line before print page break

Tags: jquery, css, printing, html-table

I am trying to print a table with modified design, where every table row is wrapped in a bootstrap "col-xs-3" class and each 4 "col-xs-3" is wrapped in "row" class like below,

```
                     <div class="row"> 
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                          <tr role="row" class="odd">
                              <td class="sorting_1">আঃ আজিজ মানিক</td>
                              <td>সাধারন সম্পাদক</td>
                              <td>ইউনয়িন আওয়ামীলীগ</td>
                              <td>০১৯২০৪৮৬০২১</td>
                              <td>শাহরাস্তি</td>
                              <td>চাঁদপুর</td>
                          </tr>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                          <tr role="row" class="even">
                              <td class="sorting_1">আবুল হোসনে পাটওয়ারী</td>
                              <td>সভাপতি</td>
                              <td>ইউনয়িন আওয়ামীলীগ</td>
                              <td>০১৭৩১৪২৪১০০</td>
                              <td>শাহরাস্তি</td>
                              <td>চাঁদপুর</td>
                          </tr>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                          <tr role="row" class="odd">
                              <td class="sorting_1">এ এইচ এম মাহে আলম</td>
                              <td>এ এস আই(নিঃ)</td>
                              <td>পুলিশ</td>
                              <td>০১৮১৭৩৮৬৬৪০</td>
                              <td>শাহরাস্তি</td>
                              <td>চাঁদপুর</td>
                          </tr>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                          <tr role="row" class="even">
                              <td class="sorting_1">কাজী নজরুল ইসলাম</td>
                              <td>সাধারন সম্পাদক</td>
                              <td>ইউনয়িন আওয়ামীলীগ</td>
                              <td>০১৭২৬৭৫০৪০২</td>
                              <td>শাহরাস্তি</td>
                              <td>চাঁদপুর</td>
                           </tr>
                        </div
                     </div>
```

The problem is when I tried to print this page it left wired small line in each page shown in image. My CSS to break page is below -

```
.row { 
  page-break-inside:avoid; 
  page-break-after:auto; 
}
```

[image]

How do I resolve this?

I have a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lr77dgmt/1384/

Comment: You cannot/should not have tr inside a div, tr elements should be in a table directly, with this invalid code you should expect all weird results.

Comment: @SamBattat I want the design showed in image from a table only for printing, that's why all this divs, otherwise this is a normal table. I didn't find any easy way to make a table like this for printing.

Comment: @LucianoFCastelfranchi which information I have to provide? I tried in jsfiddle but there is a printing issue.